# group by and create extra column of dummies in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c','a'],
             
             'col3':['A','A','B','D']})
df
```

I want to group by column1, and create extra columns showing the column 3 values, and a binary flag showing if the flag was present in that column.

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c'],           
             'col3_A':[1,1,0],
              'col3_B':[0,0,1],
              'col3_D':[1,0,0]})
```

I got to `df.groupby('col1').agg(','.join).reset_index()`, but unsure how to continue to create columns and change to binary if it exists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['col1'], df['col3']).clip(upper=1).add_prefix('col3_').reset_index()`

Comment: Or with a `pivot`: `df.assign(val=1).pivot_table(index='col1', columns='col3', values='val', aggfunc='max', fill_value=0).add_prefix('col3_').reset_index()`

Comment: Or `get_dummies`: `pd.get_dummies(df['col3'], dtype='int').groupby(df['col1']).max().add_prefix('col3_').reset_index()`